# python coroutine, perform tasks periodically and cancel

Tags: python, async-await, coroutine

```
For every 10 minutes, do the following tasks.
- generate list of image urls to download
- (if previous download is not finished, we have to cancel the download)
- download images concurrently
```

I'm relatively new to coroutines..
Can I structure the above with coroutines?

I think coroutine is essentially sequential flow..
So having problem thinking about it..

Actually, come to think of it myself, following would work?

```
async def generate_urls():

    await sleep(10)
    result = _generate_urls()
    return result

async def download_image(url):

    # download images
    image = await _download_image()
    return image

async def main():

    while True:

        urls = await generate_urls()

        for url in urls:

            download_task = asyncio.create_task(download_image(url))
            await download_task


asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You current code is quite close. Below are some modifications to make it more closely align with your original spec:

```
import asyncio
def generate_urls():
  return _generate_urls() #no need to sleep in the URL generation function

async def download_image(url):
  image = await _download_image()
  return image

async def main():
   tasks = []
   while True:
      tasks.extend(t:=[asyncio.create_task(download_image(url)) for url in generate_urls()])
      await asyncio.gather(*t) #run downloads concurrently
      await asyncio.sleep(10) #sleep after creating tasks
      for i in d: #after 10 seconds, check if any of the downloads are still running
        if not i.done():
            i.cancel() #cancel if task is not complete
```

Comment: Is there a way to send message to one of the `task`.. 
ie. Sometimes I want to pass parameter to the task, without canceling it.

I might say, I'll let you (task) know how more minutes you have before I cancel you. 
Please let me know if you think you can finish on time or not when I tell you the remaining minutes.

Comment: @eugene To do that, you would have to know the progress of the download for each task. Regardless, a form of message passing is not really necessary here: you can wrap each task with a class object that can control the checks for `done` and `cancel`, and also store how many seconds/minutes are left for each allotted task.